# Parent-Child categories duplicate problem

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, parent-child

I have the following problem. I searched everywhere and i couldn't find a similar post. I have an enum(enumerate) file which holds product categories and it's main purpose is when I start the application to fill the database with the categories. The categories are parent-children type. The problem is when I add a category, which has a parent it adds the parent again(it duplicates).

Example:
I have the following categories:

category1

- category2 *(subcategory of category1)*
- category3 *(subcategory of category1)*

In the database it will add cat1, cat2, cat3, cat1, cat1, it will duplicate the parent as many times as a new subcategory is added.

**Type.class**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "types")
public class Type extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Type parent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
private List<Type> children;
}
```

**TypeData.java (enum)**

Here I create the categories. If category should have a parent I add it, if not I leave it null.

```
@Getter
public enum TypeData {
CATEGORY_1("Category 1", null),
CATEGORY_2("Category 2", CATEGORY_1),
CATEGORY_3("Category 3", CATEGORY_1);

private final String name;
private final TypeData parent;

TypeData(String name, TypeData parent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;
}
}
```

**TypeInitialData.java**

When I start the application, this file loads categories to the database.

```
@Component
public class TypeInitialData {

private final TypeService typeService;
private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

@Autowired
public TypeInitialData(TypeService typeService, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
    this.typeService = typeService;
    this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Arrays.stream(TypeData.values())
            .forEach(x -> this.typeService.addType(this.modelMapper.map(x, Type.class)));
}
}
```

Comment: The problem is the ModelMapper which creates the same parent again when mapping and JPA sees the parent as unpersisted so it creates a new one. You should reuse persisted parent in all children.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the getter when it colides with the parent. Also the child must be one of two many, the other must be many to many. delete the second parent and add it in the database.